# How would I go about validating (using PHP) a form when the user presses submit? Want to make sure I understand this conceptually

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to understand this but I'm running into some trouble.

Basically, I have a form with some inputs in it. I have the form action set to a script that will output some things to a new page upon submission and email the user. Great.

My problem is when it comes to validating their input. I want to make sure no fields are left empty. And in the event that they are left empty, when the user presses submit I want the page to be reloaded, highlighting the boxes that were left empty and keeping their prior information.

I just don't understand how I should do this. I was thinking I could output the HTML all over again but with the fields highlighted. That works, but is quite verbose in code and the URL isn't the same as before as the URL will be the location of the processing script. I thought I could maybe validate it in the processing script then redirect them back to the original page, but then I couldn't keep their input and flag their empty inputs.

I've Googled around to try and find the proper solution, and a lot of them deal with this one where they have a php script on the initial form page ABOVE the form where they check if the user hit submit, validate it there if they did, and output the results (such as this tutorial here: http://papermashup.com/php-form-validation/). Cool, but I have some questions.

- How does this differ from a JavaScript solution that is triggered on submit? Why wouldn't I just do that?
- How can you have it above your form? I thought code reads top to bottom, so when it hit the form and you hit submit, I don't see how a form up above would trigger.
- I can't affect the CSS with this solution, can I? Such as making a box be highlighted in red?
- How do I then allow them to go to the processing script if validation is okay? I have it as the action attribute on my form, but this seemingly stops that.

What is the correct way to do this? I'm very confused.

Comment: You can validate with JS before submission and of course you should validate it in your PHP script too. You took it so far, the basic idea is to check every field's value in the form and see whether they're empty or not. Same thing goes for PHP posted values. The designing and CSS stuff is simple to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many ways to do that
First php is server side language i assume you know that and regarding the validation, it doesn't work like javascript (client side) to have the validation on the onsubmit event

one solution is to validate the form in the main page

i wrote this fast, check if i missed a quote or ... but this should do it

```
<?php

$redirect_form="";
$highlight_field="";
$error="";
$valid=true;

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"]=="Submit"){ //assuming that you have an input text called: first_name

$first_name=trim($_POST["first_name"]);

if($first_name==""){
$error.="Please enter your first name";
$highlight_field="class='highlight_field'";
$valid=false;
}

if($valid){

$redirect_form="<form name='new_page' action='new_page.php' method='post'>";
$redirect_form="<input type='hidden' name='first_name' value='".$first_name."' />";
$redirect_form="</form>";
$redirect_form="<script type='text/javascript>document.new_page.submit()</script>";

}

?>

<html>
<head>
<style>.highlight_field: color:#990000; </style>
<body>
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"]=="Submit"){

if(!$valid){
echo error;
}
else{
echo $redirect_form;
}
?>

<form name='main_page' action='main_page.php' method='post'>
<span <?php echo $highlight_field; ?>>First name</span><input type='text' name='first_name' value='' />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />

</form>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

or you can do it with ajax